# Naming conflicts between different libraries

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my program with two statically linked libraries: SFML and PhysFS. However, at the linking phase I get the following errors:

> eror LNK2005: _inflatePrime already defined in sfml-graphics-s.lib(inflate.obj)
>   error LNK2005: _inflateGetHeader already defined in sfml-graphics-s.lib(inflate.obj)
>   error LNK2005: _adler32_combine already defined in sfml-graphics-s.lib(adler32.obj)
>   error LNK2005: _crc32_combine already defined in sfml-graphics-s.lib(crc32.obj)
>   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

What should I do when two entirely unrelated libraries have this kind of conflicts?

Edit: Oh please-please tell me I'm not going to have to write a wrapper. I'm so tired of having to get things to work, I just want to write my own code already. :(

Comment: First question are you using C or C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both libraries seems to have preferred to include the zlib library instead of having a dependency on it.  I'd try to build them without this inclusion and link the executable with zlib.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was worried I'd have to go through another round of nerve-wrecking work. If anyone else has a similar problem and they are using Visual Studio, take a look at this link for a quick and dirty temporary solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the library source code, this may be as simple as adding a couple of namespaces. In library A's header file:

```
namespace LibA {

   // existing function declarations

}
```

and in the C++ source files:

```
namespace LibA {

    // existing code

}
```

Same for library B, but with a different namespace name. I realise this is a pain, but if the libraries really do have name clashes, it is the cleanest approach.